# jquery load page content into div using a stored var

Tags: jquery, load, var, submenu

I can't explain this but I'm trying to auto detect the page, and place the corresponding submenu for that page...

BASICALLY MY QUESTION IS HOW DO I WRITE THIS LINE...OR??

```
$( "#navsubmenu" ).load("Templates/navigation.html", submenu);
```

### here is a bit of background:

```
//detect url
var page = window.location.href;
//strip off url address and get page name
var page_name = page.substring(page.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
//concatenate string nav-submenu to page name and strip off html to get the submenu name

var submenu = '.nav-submenu-' + page_name.substr(0, page_name.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

in this example it is the index page:

```
<ul class="nav-submenu-index">
  <li class="sectionTitle">OF INTEREST</li>
  <li><a href="#">Link #1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link #2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link #3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link #4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link #5</a></li>
</ul>
```

so basically submenu will be nav-submenu-index if the page loaded is index.html

but I don't know how to write it correctly, this doens't work:

```
$( "#navsubmenu" ).load("Templates/navigation.html submenu");
```

I tried this and got **ALL** the menus on the while page, not the actual fragment:

```
$( "#navsubmenu" ).load("Templates/navigation.html", submenu);
```

and the div it writes into is just:

```
<div id="aside"></div>
```

Comment: If you forgot to say something, edit the question to add it.

Comment: Thanks I found it...wasn't sure where the edit link was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string concatenation:

```
$("#navsubmenu").load("Templates/navication.html " + submenu);
```

Comment: Thanks it works...you're awesome and I feel so silly, it had to be that simple lol!